# Why does gradle not take the Version from AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I need to compare the Version of the App with the Version on a Server, but why does the Gradle versionCode of the App stay 1 although my versionCode in the Manifest is 114?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings in Gradle replace those in the manifest, such as `versionCode`. Either:

- remove `versionCode` from your `build.gradle` file, or
- put the right `versionCode` in `build.gradle` and remove the `android:versionCode` from your manifest